# Can a function return a closure taking String arguments and return values?

Tags: rust, closures

If I'm returning a closure defined as such:

```
fn closure_thing() -> (Fn(String) -> String) {
    |thing| {
        thing[1..4]
    }
}
```

I receive an error of:

```
= note: `std::ops::Fn(std::string::String) -> std::string::String + 'static` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
= note: the return type of a function must have a statically known size`
```

I have tried `Fn(&String) -> &String` as well.  Is there an easy way for a closure to take a string as an argument and return a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Fn` is a trait. You can't return a trait. You can return a function pointer though:

```
fn closure_thing() -> (fn(String) -> String) {
    fn foo(thing: String) -> String {
        …
    }

    foo
}
```

You can also return a `Box`:

```
fn closure_thing() -> Box<Fn(String) -> String> {
    Box::new(|thing| {
        …
    })
}
```

But that one has a runtime cost, so should be considered as a last resort.

As mentioned by @Veedrac, you can also use `impl Trait`:

```
#![feature(conservative_impl_trait)]

fn closure_thing() -> impl Fn(String) -> String {
    |thing| {
        …
    }
}
```

But as of Rust 1.12 this is not stable yet and requires a nightly compiler. It allows you to return any trait, without the runtime cost of the previous solution.

Comment: Your first two have a (potential) runtime cost, too, since they involve dynamic dispatch. AFAIK the only solution is to use `impl Trait`.

Comment: You should probably mention that your first example won't work directly as the closure doesn't last long enough (unless I am missing something).

Comment: @ErikVesteraas TIL borrowck runs after the “main function not found” which is a fatal error

Comment: @mcarton by runtime cost, do you mean the cost of heap allocation? Or is there something more involved with rust's Box?

Comment: @JeffQuick the cost is a heap allocation once + dynamic dispatch every time the function is called. As @veedrac mentioned, `-> impl Trait` is also a solution if working on a nightly is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

> the return type of a function must have a statically known size

One way to achieve that is to box the closure...

```
fn closure_thing() -> Box<Fn(String) -> String> {
    Box::new(|thing| {
        (&thing[1..4]).to_string()
    })
}
```

Note that I also converted the result to a `String`.. since slicing it will return a `str`.

As noted by mcarton, boxing will incur a runtime cost for the heap allocation.